# How to set an intial joint state to a robot arm in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint-state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to give an initial joint state to a robot arm in gazebo? (e.g. from the launch file setting)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242465/how-to-set-an-intial-joint-state-to-a-robot-arm-in-gazebo/) by [johnyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26493/johnyang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example of how to do it from a launch file:

```
<node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
      args="-urdf -model mbot -param robot_description -x 0.5 -y 0.5 -z 0.01 
      -J left_arm_joint0 0.0
      -J left_arm_joint1 1.18
      -J left_arm_joint2 0.12
      -J left_arm_joint3 0.92
      -J left_arm_joint4 0.24
      -J left_arm_joint5 0.63
      -J left_arm_joint6 0.44" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2017-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1